# UITextChecker in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uitextchecker

I get an error while using UITextChecker in Swift 4. The following code most likely works for Swift 3, I'm just not sure what's the problem in Swift 4? Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
var correctStr : String = String()
let str = "Helo"
let textChecker = UITextChecker()
let misspelledRange = textChecker.rangeOfMisspelledWordInString(
            str, range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count),
            startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")

        if misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound,
            let guesses = textChecker.guessesForWordRange(
                misspelledRange, inString: str, language: "en_US") as? [String]
        {
            correctStr = guesses.first

        }
```

and I receive this error:
"use of unresolved identifier 'UITextChecker'.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that playground?

Comment: no, it's xcode.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same error with your code and Xcode 9.0.1. Create a new project and try your code on the new project.

Comment: Did you try cleaning and rebuilding your project? Make sure your project platform is iOS or tvOS. UITextChecker does not exist on macOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The APIs `rangeOfMisspelledWordInString` and `guessesForWordRange` have been renamed, your code should read:

```
import UIKit
var correctStr : String = String()
let str = "Helo"
let textChecker = UITextChecker()

let misspelledRange = textChecker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: str, range: NSRange(0..<str.utf16.count), startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: "en_US")
if misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound,
  let guesses = textChecker.guesses(forWordRange: misspelledRange, in: str, language: "en_US") {
  correctStr = guesses.first!
}
```

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error. I'm getting an error on line 4 of my code above, it seems that it's not able to create a new instance of UITextChecker!

Comment: Running the above code verbatim works in XCode 9.0.1 for me -- can you check the same?